# Relationship between NORG and Martine

Tags: final-fantasy-8

I'm doing my billionth playthrough of FFVIII, and there's something that still doesn't quite stick, lore-wise.

When we confront Garden Master NORG, he says that Martine (Galbadia's Garden Master) is one of his subordinates. However, Martine gave us the order to assassinate Edea without NORG's permission.

Then again, NORG despises Edea and Cid.

**Question:**

What's the relationship between NORG and Martine? And why did Martine decide to give the order to assassinate Edea when Edea is seemingly in control of Galbadia?

Comment: Hi Alec, lore questions are on topic here, but some people just don't like them. Please don't get discouraged if you receive down votes.

Comment: However, posting the exact same question on two sites would typically be discouraged.

Comment: @TZHX - Thanks. I'll leave it here then, and delete the one on SciFi/Fantasy. It seemed like they both fit the bill.

Answer (score 2):

The [final fantasy wiki](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Martine) has your answer:

> Although the relationship with the Galbadian government afforded Galbadia Garden a great deal of power and influence, it made it vulnerable to Galbadia's political leanings. When Galbadian President Vinzer Deling begins to fall under the enchanting Sorceress Ultimecia's influence (using Edea Kramer's body and name), Martine grows concerned, fearing the sorceress's growing power would spill over into his Garden.

As for NORG, it was he and Cid who first started the Gardens(Balamb being the original).  This makes him the overseer of all the gardens so to speak, since he funds them all.  So he sees all the headmasters as his subordinates.  And it was his idea to start hiring out the SeeDs as mercenaries.  He is only concerned with profit, however, so chooses to not confront the sorceress since that would result in a loss of profit.  This is why he was furious that the Gardens were involved in the assassination attempt as he does not believe in the true purpose of the Gardens, only profit.